# How to consume WebAPI from a content editor web part

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

```
<div id="body">
 <ul id="contacts"></ul>
 <form id="saveContactForm" method="post">
     <h3>Create a new Contact</h3>
     <p>
         <label for="contactId">Contact Id:</label>
         <input type="text" name="Id" />
     </p>
     <p>
         <label for="contactName">Contact Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Name" />
    </p>
     <input type="button" id="saveContact" value="Save" />
 </form>
</div>
   @section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON('/api/contact', function (contactsJsonPayload) {
            $(contactsJsonPayload).each(function (i, item) {
                $('#contacts').append('<li>' + item.Name + '</li>');
            });
         });
    });
    $('#saveContact').click(function () {
        $.post("api/contact",
              $("#saveContactForm").serialize(),
              function (value) {
                  $('#contacts').append('<li>' + value.Name + '</li>');
              },
              "json"
        );
    });
  </script>
 }
```

I have written the above code for consuming web api from a SP2013 content editor web part.

But am not able to get any output.
What am i missing here?

Comment: Could you please share screen shot and Error which is logged in console?

Comment: I am not getting any error. But on click of save button nothing happens

Comment: After save click, there must be an error in the browser console?

Comment: @Akshay you are correct after save click there should be error, and in sharepoint $ will not work exactly how it works in JQuery so make sure you have refered JQuery file and try using jQuery instead of $